# Chosing the right type of event to handle in WinPhone

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a playing board in the page:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Squares"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border 
                            Background="{Binding Status, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource SquareStatusToBrushConverter}}"
                            Tag="{Binding StraightCoord}"
                            micro:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter] = [Action HandleMouseEnterOnCell($source)]">
                        <TextBlock 
                                   Text="{Binding Letter}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

It consists of squares presented by borders (which contain text blocks). I need to give an ability to user to select a sequence of squares holding a finger on the screen (without separate clicks).

In order to accomplish that, I decided to handle MouseEnter event and there is something strange happening.
When I set a breakpoint at the beginning of the MouseEnter event handler I reach it and press F5. Everything works fine. When I turn off that breakpoint, it seems that MouseEnter starts to be fired twice and I receive my own validation exception which says that the user can't choose the same square more than once. Of course I will handle that exception. But in the described case I even don't expect it to be fired!

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to accomplish such a task using other events? And why if you have a suggestion the MouseEnter event fired twice with no breakpoints?

Comment: `MouseEnter` is bubbling event so if you catch it on `Border` I would expect it to fire for `Border` and everything inside so also `TextBlock` in your case

Comment: So how to handle it only once, check the OriginalSource of event?

Comment: Try and check if `e.OriginalSource is Border` and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Just set UIElement.IsHitTestVisible to false for the parts you don;t want to trigger

Comment: Didn't help! I thought it would! But not, it didn't!

Comment: Add your xaml here so I can see what you're doing then I might be able to help.